# Placing window on two displays with different resolution in same point

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Is there a way to place window in the same point for example in top-right corner on the to displays with different resolution?

For example you have Macbook and you connected it to big display.

Note: windows property "Spaces" in IB is set to "Can join all spaces"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces and displays are two separate concepts. So, "Can join all spaces" is not relevant to your question.

A window can only be at one position in the global screen coordinate system that spans the whole desktop. Each display constitutes a separate part of that coordinate system (ignoring mirroring). Therefore, no, it's not possible to have a window show up in the top-right corner of two separate displays. You would need two separate windows to achieve that.